# List last modified sub-directories in a directory

Tags: powershell

I have one test directory with sub-directories:

```
C:\test
    - test1
          - test-1-1
                    - DIR1
                          - 1.0
          - test-1-2
                    - DIR2  => Latest modified sub dir
                          - 1.1
    - test2
          - test-2-1 
                    - DIR1  => Latest modified sub dir
                          - 1.3
          - test-2-2
                    - DIR1
                          - 1.2
```

Could be possible to output for every sub-directory in test, the name and the version of latest modified sub directory. Assuming that DIR1 or DIR2 can be any name.

Final view to be like more:

```
test-1-2 1.1
test-2-1 1.3
```

For now only output which I can get is that which get only latest `test*-*-*` but not DIR*:

```
gci 'C:\test' |where { $_.psiscontainer } |foreach { get-childitem $_.name |sort creationtime | select -expand name -last 1 }

    PS C:\test> gci 'C:\test' |where { $_.psiscontainer } |foreach { get-childitem $_.name |sort creationtime | select -expand name -last 1 }
test-1-2
test-2-1
```

Comment: [1] your example of desired output does NOT match what you seem to be describing. the following is missing the `DIR1` >> `test-2-1 1.3` << ///// [2] what version of PoSh are you using? v3 has a `-Directory` parameter for `Get-ChildItem`. ///// [3] once you have a directory, you can use the `.Parent` property will give you the dir that contains that item.

Comment: In general I want to output version directory which Parent directory in that Case DIR* is last modified and to show only that version not all of them. So in the first example should to be output only ```test-1-2 1.1```

Comment: ok ---- but you keep referring to `DIR*` as being the newest ... and then only showing the parent and child of that newest dir. this is NOT what you keep describing. [*frown*]

Answer (score -2):

I don't quite understand your question. Could you possibly try to re-phrase the question, or give more/different examples?

I took a guess at what you are trying to achieve. Have a look at the below code.

I assumed your folder structure would always be the same. The output will show you the latest of the folders called "DIR" in each test-*-* folder. I kind of organised the depth of the folders into 'levels' hoping to make things a little clearer.

I often find that using ForEach and s a scriptblock gives you more control over the data than using 'ForEach-Object' in a pipe.

```
$Level1 = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\test" -Directory

ForEach ($D1 in $Level1)
{
    Write-Host "Getting ChildItem of DIR: $($D1.FullName)"

    $Level2 = Get-ChildItem -Path $D1.FullName -Directory

    ForEach ($D2 in $Level2)
    {
        Write-Host "Getting ChildItem of DIR: $($D2.FullName)`n`n"

        $LastModDir = Get-ChildItem -Path $D2.FullName -Directory | Sort-Object CreationTime | Select-Object Name -Last 1

        Write-Host "$D2 $($LastModDir.Name)"
    }
}
```

Output:

```
test-1-1 DIR1
test-1-2 DIR2
test-2-1 DIR1
test-2-2 DIR2
```

Even if this isn't what you were trying to achieve, the the techniques might be useful for you to achieve your goal.

EDIT:
I just noticed you want to sort the 1.1 etc folders, not the DIR folders. Just add another 'level' with a ForEach loop.

Comment: I want to output only latest modified sub-dirs and their children directory (which suppose to be the version), not all of them.